# React-Leaflet draw circle markers on map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geometry, marker, react-leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet/React-Leaflet and I am trying to plot a circle marker on a map and I'm having trouble. React-Leaflet's documentation is not very good. I have figured out how to add a popup that shows on click though.

Here's my code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, Tooltip, Circle } from 'react-leaflet';
import DivIcon from 'react-leaflet-div-icon';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class MapView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      nasaLocations: [],
      spacexLocations: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gvk9-iz74.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const nasaData = res.data;
        this.setState({nasaLocations: nasaData})
        console.log(this.state.nasaLocations);
      })

    axios.get(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launchpads`)
      .then(res => {
        const spacexData = res.data;
        this.setState({spacexLocations: spacexData})
        console.log(this.state.spacexLocations);
      })
  }


render() {
   const position = [40.730610, -73.935242];
    return (
        <Map
          style={{height: "100vh"}}
          center={position}
          zoom={3}>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/nicknyr/cje7mtk2y6gf92snsydobiahf/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja255ciIsImEiOiJjajduNGptZWQxZml2MndvNjk4eGtwbDRkIn0.L0aWwfHlFJVGa-WOj7EHaA"
            attribution="<attribution>" />
          <Marker position={position}>
            <Popup>
              <span>
                A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
              </span>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
    );
  }

}
```

How can I render a circle on those position coordinates? I've attemped to add a  type tag within the Map tag but I can't figure out the proper syntax and how to properly add lat/long coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have little experience with Leaflet, but I got a circle to render, here is the example.  I passed the latlng coords using an obj.  Hope this helps. If this didn't answer the question, let me know. Circles show up on each location, with the pop-up showing the details from the space x api.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Tooltip,Popup, Circle} from 'react-leaflet';
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launchpads';
const leafURL = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/nicknyr/cje7mtk2y6gf92snsydobiahf/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoibmlja255ciIsImEiOiJjajduNGptZWQxZml2MndvNjk4eGtwbDRkIn0.L0aWwfHlFJVGa-WOj7EHaA";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latlng: {
      lat: 28.5618571,
      lng: -80.577366,
      },
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      this.setState({data: res.data})
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('error')
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          style={{height: "100vh"}}
          center={this.state.latlng}
          zoom={4}>
          <TileLayer
            url={leafURL}
            attribution="<attribution>" />
          {data.map((elem, i) => {
            return (
              <Marker 
                key={i} 
                position={{lat:elem.location.latitude, lng: elem.location.longitude}}>
                <Popup>
                  <span>
                    {elem.full_name}<br />
                    {elem.status}<br />
                    {elem.details}<br />
                    {elem.vehicles_launched.map((elem, i) => {
                      return ( <p key={i}>{elem}</p>)
                    })}
                  </span>
                </Popup>
                <Circle 
                  center={{lat:elem.location.latitude, lng: elem.location.longitude}}
                  fillColor="blue" 
                  radius={200}/>
              </Marker>
            )
          })}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```